# Why does Bundler report "Could not find capistrano-2.11.1 in any of the sources"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Bundler version 1.0.22

Deploying to RedHat Linux 6

Ruby 1.9.3p0

Rails 3.2.1

---

I read the Bundler docs and took these steps...

- Got everything set on dev workstation so all the gems are installed and the app works and tests pass.
- Checked `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` into source control. Made sure not to check `.bundle` into source control.

I ran `$ cap deploy`. Now my code is on the production server.

Following the instructions in the [docs](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html), I log in, cd to my app root, and run...

```
$ bundle install --development
```

This is the result...

```
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
Could not find capistrano-2.11.1 in any of the sources
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error is occurring?

Any idea how I can persuade Bundler to install my required gems?

I tried to find a clue from what Bundler considers to be the gem environment...

```
$ bundle exec gem environment
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
```

I looked at the Bundler troubleshooting page and followed the instructions there to delete a bunch of stuff...

```
# remove user-specific gems and git repos
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/

# remove system-wide git repos and git checkouts
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ $GEM_HOME/cache/bundler/

# remove project-specific settings and git repos
rm -rf .bundle/

# remove project-specific cached .gem files
rm -rf vendor/cache/

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile
#
# For now, did not delete this. If I understand the Bundler docs correctly,
# this file is sort of the whole point of Bundler. If I delete it, my deployed
# dependencies won't be the same as in development.
# rm -rf Gemfile.lock

# try to install one more time
bundle install
```

Bundler still says...

```
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
Could not find capistrano-2.11.1 in any of the sources
```

OK, fine. I'll remove `Gemfile.lock`...

```
$ bundle install --deployment
The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked 
    your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
```

I would be grateful for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version of Capistrano was yanked and is no longer available from rubygems.org. You can see that on the versions page https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano/versions

Comment: What about rake-0.9.2.2? That hasn't been yanked as far as I can tell. Do you have any thoughts on why Bundler, in general, is not functioning as advertised on my system.

Comment: To be honest, I made it to the part where I realized you were using a version of Capistrano that was yanked and didn't read any further. It's probably an incomplete bundle install. Revert your Gemfile.lock deletion and update the version of Capistrano. If the exact version isn't specified in Gemfile, then run `bundle update capistrano`. If it is, then just change it to the next available version.

Comment: OK, done. You were right. `bundle install --development` was able to continue further. (Until it got to nokogiri and choked on that. But that's another issue.)

Comment: Nokogiri is written in C as opposed to just ruby, so you will need to be able to compile C. I'm not a Linux person, but I bet it's easy to figure out what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Got here by having a similar rake-0.9.2.2 error. Figured out that I left out the appropriate `require` to include the bundler specific capistrano tasks in my deploy.rb file:

**In your deploy.rb:**

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'delayed/recipes'
```

This ends up running the `bundle install` for you (with some nice command line args).

Also, you don't need capistrano on your application server. You can let bundler know that in the `Gemfile` like so:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
end
```

Now with `cap deploy`, cap tells bundler to ignore the the `development` and `test` groups, which results in not installing capistrano (and other development or testing tools) on the production server.

Comment: yes! capistrano isn't needed in development, this to me is the best solution and worked for me.